# Doubt regarding fibre bundles under group action

Tags: algebraic-geometry, fiber-bundles

Let $X, Y$ be smooth projective varieties over $\mathbb{C} $, and let $\pi: Y \rightarrow X$ be a zariski-locally trivial fibre bundle map with smooth fibre $F$. Moreover, let a finite group $\Gamma$ act freely on both $X$ and $Y$, such that $\pi$ is $\Gamma$-equivariant. It is known that both the quotients $X':=X/\Gamma$ and $Y':=Y/\Gamma$ exist as smooth varieties.

Now, because of equivariance, $\pi$ will induce a map $\pi': Y'\rightarrow X'$. My question is:
Is $\pi'$ also a fibre bundle map with same fibre $F$?

I think it should be true; my idea is that if $U$ is a locally trivial neighborhood in $X$ such that $Y|_{U} \simeq U\times F$, then $\pi(U) $ should be locally trivial for $\pi'$. Is this correct?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there exist many counterexamples such as follows:

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a Galois cover of curves whose Galois group is $G = \mathrm{Aut}(X/Y)$.
Assume that the genus $g(Y)$ of $Y$ is greater than $2$, then by Riemann-Hurwitz formula, it holds that $g(X) > g(Y)$.
Consider the trivial fiber bundle $p:X\times X \to X$ (second projection) and $G$-action, where $G$ acts on $X\times X$ by diagonal.
It is clear that $p$ is compatible with both $G$-action on $X\times X$ and $X$.
Hence we can consider the quotient $q: Q = (X\times X)/G \to Y$.
Then each fiber of $q$ is isomophic to $X$, but $q$ is not Zariski-trivial.

Let us prove that $q$ is not Zariski-trivial.
Assume that there exists a Zariski open subset $V\subset Y$ and local trivialization $X\times V \cong Q\times_Y V$.
Write $U := f^{-1}(V) \subset X$, $r:X\times X\to Q$ for the quotient morphism, and $i:U \to X\times X$ for the diagonal.
Then $i$ is compatible with $G$-action, so we obtain a morphism $j:V\to Q$ such that $j\circ f|_U = r\circ i$.
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
U @>{i}>> X\times X @>{p}>> X \\
@V{f|_U}VV @V{r}VV  @VV{f}V \\
V @>{j}>> Q @>{q}>> Y. 
\end{CD}
$$
Note that the both squares in the above diagram are Cartesian.
Since $q$ is trivial over $V$, by composing $(j,q\circ j):V\to Q\times_Y V$, the isomorphism $Q\times_YV \cong X\times V$, and the first projection $X\times V \to X$, we obtain a morphism $g:V\to X$.
Moreover, $g$ is not constant because $i$ is the diagonal.
By extending $g: V \to X$ to $Y\to X$ and using Riemann-Hurwits formula, we conclude that $g(Y) > g(X)$, and this contradicts to the inequality $g(X) > g(Y)$.

Comment: Nice answer! +1

Comment: thank you, Alex 

Comment: @YJ_cat : Thank you for this nice counterexample! May I ask : what would be the case if the group $\Gamma$ is acting by fixing the fiber? In your example, the fiber is also changing. Actually, the case I'm interseted in has the fibers fixed under the group action. It would be great if something can be said about such cases as well.

Comment: I may not fully understand that you asked. But I think if you say there exists a point $x\in X$ (as your first notation) such that the fiber of $x$ is fixed by the $\Gamma$-action on $Y$, then $x$ is a fixed point of the $\Gamma$-action on $X$, so it contradicts to your asummption that $\Gamma$ acts on $X$ freely. Please comment if I have misunderstanding about that you said.

Comment: @YJ_cat : Sorry for the confusion. What I mean is that suppose I take a point $x\in X$ and $g\in \Gamma$. Then $g$ will take the fiber over $x$ to the fiber over $g\cdot x$, and both fibres are isomorphic to $F$ by assumption. I meant that this induced map on $F$ is identity, for each $g\in \Gamma$ and $x\in X$.

Comment: I still not fully understand. I think the morphism $F\to F$ induced by $g\in \Gamma$ depends on a choice of isomorphisms $F\cong \pi^{-1}(x)\cong \pi^{-1}(gx)$. If you define $F := \pi^{-1}(x)$, and you choose $g:F \xrightarrow{\sim} \pi^{-1}(gx)$ (multiplying $g$), then $g$ induces identity on $F$, so I think your question is still ill-defined.